# Install PHP ZIP extension in MAMP Pro

Tags: php, mamp, php-extension, mamp-pro, php-ziparchive

I am trying to Install PHP ZIP extension in MAMP Pro.

I followed many tutorials, and official one:

[MAMP Documentation](https://appsolute.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360026433951-My-intl-extension-is-missing-)

But didn't get the job done at all.

Here's what I get when installing from terminal using `sudo pecl install zip`:

```
downloading zip-1.18.0.tgz ...
Starting to download zip-1.18.0.tgz (296,922 bytes)
.............................................................done: 296,922 bytes
14 source files, building
running: phpize
grep: /usr/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:
Zend Module Api No:
Zend Extension Api No:
building in /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootRigCsc/zip-1.18.0
running: /private/tmp/pear/install/zip/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin19.2.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin19.2.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin19.2.0
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking if awk is broken... no
checking for zip archive read/writesupport... yes, shared
checking libzip... yes
checking PHP version... 7.3
checking for pkg-config... no
checking for libzip... in default path: found in /usr/local
checking for zip_open in -lzip... yes
checking for zip_file_set_mtime in -lzip... yes
checking for zip_file_set_encryption in -lzip... yes
checking for zip_libzip_version in -lzip... yes
checking for zip_register_progress_callback_with_state in -lzip... yes
checking for zip_register_cancel_callback_with_state in -lzip... yes
checking for ld used by cc... /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 196608
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking for dsymutil... dsymutil
checking for nmedit... nmedit
checking for -single_module linker flag... yes
checking for -exported_symbols_list linker flag... yes
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... yes
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fno-common
checking if cc PIC flag -fno-common works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... no
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the cc linker (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin19.2.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no

creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
running: make
/bin/sh /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootRigCsc/zip-1.18.0/libtool --mode=compile cc -I/usr/local/include -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/install/zip -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootRigCsc/zip-1.18.0/include -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootRigCsc/zip-1.18.0/main -I/private/tmp/pear/install/zip -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/private/tmp/pear/install/zip/php73  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /private/tmp/pear/install/zip/php73/php_zip.c -o php73/php_zip.lo
mkdir php73/.libs
 cc -I/usr/local/include -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/install/zip -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootRigCsc/zip-1.18.0/include -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootRigCsc/zip-1.18.0/main -I/private/tmp/pear/install/zip -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/private/tmp/pear/install/zip/php73 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /private/tmp/pear/install/zip/php73/php_zip.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o php73/.libs/php_zip.o
/private/tmp/pear/install/zip/php73/php_zip.c:24:10: fatal error: 'php.h' file not found
#include "php.h"
         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [php73/php_zip.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

PHP and PECL info:

```
PHP 7.3.9 (cli) (built: Nov  9 2019 08:08:13) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.9, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

PEAR Version: 1.10.10
PHP Version: 7.3.9
Zend Engine Version: 3.3.9
Running on: Darwin CairoCoder-2.local 19.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.2.0: Sat Nov  9 03:47:04 PST 2019; root:xnu-6153.61.1~20/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

OSX Version:

```
OSX Catalina: 10.15.2 (19C57)
```

Comment: did you find a solution yet?